# How to start an SVN project from the command line?

Tags: svn

So I have a ruby on rails application that I have created on my local computer. I have a remote repository that I've created. Now how do I check it in for the first time? I have never created my own svn project before, so I don't know how to do it. I've only made commits to projects that I've worked on.

### Solution:

```
cd [my project dir]
svn import -m "First Check-in" svn://[SubversionRunningMachine]/[ProjectName]/trunk
```

This will check in the project. Now you have to check out the project.

```
svn co svn://[SubversionRunningMachine]/[ProjectName]/trunk NewProjectName
```

Answer (score 61):

There are actually two ways to do this.  One is through the use of import which doesn't put your active code base under version control.  The other method is to just create an empty project in the repository and then check it out directly into the code base.  Then just do an add and an a commit:

```
svn mkdir <repo>/newProject
svn checkout <repo>/newProject /path/to/codebase
svn add /path/to/codebase/*
svn commit /path/to/codebase -m "adding initial codebase"
```

There is a good tutorial on how to create a new project here: http://web.archive.org/web/20110316170621/http://www.duchnik.com/tutorials/vc/svn-command-reference

Comment: For me, this is the most convenient method. I also like to add the `-m` switch to the first command, to prevent svn from opening the default editor:

`svn mkdir <repo>/newProject -m "Creating dir for newProject"`

Comment: Didn't realize you could check out into an existing folder without overwriting it; that's handy.

Answer (score 8):

You have to create the repository on the server first, then use the **[svn import](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html)** command:

```
svn import <<URL>> -m<<comment>>
```

This will add all of your files to the repository and then commit them in one step.

Alternatively, you can check out the empty repository (you should have at least **/trunk**, **/tags**, and **/branches**, check out **/trunk**) and then copy all of your files into the new working copy and add only the files/directories you want to commit. I prefer this method.

Comment: I prefer this method as it requires less steps and if you add the folder name to URL (URL/folderName), it will also add a folder where the project is imported

Comment: I tried this method, seemed to work, but when I do svn info, it says Not Found, and "some targets don't exist".

Answer (score 0):

See below screnshot ...[image]

First you need to create a directory(pathToProject in this case) and then you just need to apply svn checkout command! After that to check if its really working or not, just modify any of the file and commit it to check if your changes are successfully applied or not.

```
$ svn update
$ svn commit
```

Comment: On `svn update` produce `svn: E155007: None of the targets are working copies`